# Reading and displaying a 64 bit number in assembly

Tags: assembly, 32bit-64bit

I'm working on a project in assembly, using Notepad++. I need to read two 64 bit numbers from an expression and for that I used sscanf. When I display first number I used dword ptr no1 to represent the last 32 bits from the number and dword ptr no1+4 for the other bits. It didn't work. Also, if necessarly I can use only 32 bit register.

It's the formatNumber correct?  I tried %d, %lld but it didn't worked as expected. Also, the method I used to display the number is correct?

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall

includelib msvcrt.lib
 extern printf: proc
extern exit: proc
extern scanf: proc
extern exit: proc
extern sscanf: proc
extern exit: proc
public start

.data

msg db 13,10, "Insert expression : ",0
formatExpression db "%s",0  ; expression example : 5446722+31 or 3*61244
formatNumber db "%ld",0
format db "%ld%c%ld",0 ; to read datas from expression
expression db 100 dup(0)
no1 dq 0 
no2 dq 0
operation dd 0

.code
start:  

push offset msg
call printf
add esp , 4

; reading expression
push offset expression
push offset formatExpression
call scanf 
add esp, 8

;reading data
push offset no2
push offset operation
push offset no1
push offset format
push offset expression
call sscanf 
add esp,20

;display first number

push dword ptr no1+4
push offset formatNumber
call printf
add  esp,8  

push dword ptr no1
push offset formatNumber
call printf
add  esp,8

push 0
call exit
end start
```

Comment: do you have access to qword? and isn't %ld for longs (which don't need to be 64 bits?) shouldn't you use %lld?

Comment: What OS are you under?  Notepad implies Windows.  What arch?  32 bit or 64 bit?  The answers make a difference as to what is the correct asm sequence due to differences in how Windows deals with longs vs other POSIX OSes.

Comment: I have 64 bit Windows. I tried to use %lld for reading and for displaying the number, but on the screen the number I displayed was different from the number I read